# Microsoft Graph API call to /me endpoint failing with error: compactToken 80049217

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm making calls (JavaScript) from an Outlook add-in to the Graph API. In particular calls to /me. The majority of these calls succeed but beginning 26-Feb-2019 I've started seeing a small number of these calls returning the following error:

CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

A number of the users who experienced the issue have been able to successfully make the same call when reattempted later.

The vast majority of the calls are succeeding which makes me think there's nothing wrong with how the bearer token is being provided to the Graph API (i.e. for every 1000 calls made to the Graph /Me endpoint I'm seeing 2 or 3 instances of this error)

Structure of the HTTPS call being made:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,assignedPlans